# how can i post json to google people.api

Tags: json, vba, contacts, google-people-api

by creating an contact,
i always get the answer

Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name

my strJson is

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "familyName": "NN"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
Set web_HTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    web_Url_CreateContacts = "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact"
    web_HTTP.Open "Post", web_Url_CreateContacts & "?" & _
        "access_token=" & Token & "&" & _
        "key=" & ApiKey & "&" & _
        strJson
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting the strJson as part of the query string which would mean it should be urlencoded probably. But I would discourage that. It's better to post with the RequestBody parameter of winHTTP, than trying to put it all in one string. and posting.

```
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

   'list
    '~~> Indicates that page that will receive the request and the type of request being 
    submitted
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", 
    "https://www.example.com/api/go/XSx/rest/inquiry/resolveXInquiry", False
    '~~> Indicate that the body of the request contains form data
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    ''or JSON content type
    '~~> Send the data as name/value pairs
    '["50061555", "50055854", "500615516", "500615576", "50055910"]
    xmlhttp.send "request={""inquiryIds"":[50061333],""requestType"":""Report2"",""from"":""*parameter"",""comment"":""report""}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

That was the idea I was missing!

strJSON must be sent as a body (XMLHttpRequest.send (body)).